# Huggingface Trainer load_best_model f1 score vs. loss and overfitting

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I have trained a roberta-large and specified `load_best_model_at_end=True` and `metric_for_best_model=f1`. During training, I can see overfitting after the 6th epoch, which is the sweetspot. In Epoch 8, which is the next one to evaluate due to gradient accumulation, we can see that train loss decreases and eval_loss increases. Thus, overfitting starts. The transformers trainer in the end loads the model from epoch 8, checkpoint `-14928`, as the f1 score is a bit highea. I was wondering, in theory, wouldn't be the model from epoch 6 be better suited, as it did not overfit? Or does one really go for the f1 metric here even though the model did overfit? (the eval loss decreased in epochs <6 constantly).

The test_loss from the second checkpoint, which is then loaded as the "best", is 0.128. Is it possible to lower that using the first checkpoint which should be the better model anyway?

```
checkpoint-11196:
{'loss': 0.0638, 'learning_rate': 8.666799323450404e-06, 'epoch': 6.0}

{'eval_loss': 0.09599845856428146, 'eval_accuracy': 0.9749235986101227, 'eval_precision': 0.9648319293367138, 'eval_recall': 0.9858766505097777, 'eval_f1': 0.9752407721241682, 'eval_runtime': 282.2294, 'eval_samples_per_second': 84.637, 'eval_steps_per_second': 2.647, 'epoch': 6.0}

VS.

checkpoint-14928:
{'loss': 0.0312, 'learning_rate': 7.4291115311909265e-06, 'epoch': 8.0}

{'eval_loss': 0.12377820163965225, 'eval_accuracy': 0.976305103194206, 'eval_precision': 0.9719324391455539, 'eval_recall': 0.9810295838208257, 'eval_f1': 0.9764598236566295, 'eval_runtime': 276.7619, 'eval_samples_per_second': 86.309, 'eval_steps_per_second': 2.699, 'epoch': 8.0}
```

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just comment the `metric_for_best_model='f1'` part out and see for yourself, loss is the default setting. Or, utilize `from_pretrained('path/to/checkpoint')` to compare two checkpoints back to back. F-score is threshold sensitive, so it's entirely possible for a lower loss checkpoint to be better in the end (assuming you do optimize the threshold).

Comment: Thank you, I have overlooked the default setting. Can "load_best_model_at_the_end" also be chosen based on the test_loss instead of the eval_loss?

Comment: I could save all checkpoints and evaluate for myself, if there is a shortcut, I would be happy to hear.

Comment: I wouldn't advise it since that's a test data leakage. Selecting a best model is exactly what evaluation set exists for.

Personally, I'd run something like that in a loop for a deeper insight on checkpoint performance:

    model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('path', num_labels=2)
    probs = softmax(Trainer(model).predict(test_set).predictions, axis=1)[:,1]
    precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(test_set['labels'], probs)
    f1s = 2*recall*precision/(recall+precision)
    best_f1 = np.max(f1s)
    best_thresh = thresholds[np.argmax(f1s)]